# How to get pretty printed JSON with Keras model.to_json()?

Tags: python, json, keras

I am trying to [save model to JSON with Keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) and getting condensed JSON code.

Is it possible to save in pretty-printed human friendly JSON here?

Comment: `pprint` https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html

Comment: @DeepSpace where do you see it can reparse string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`to_json` method](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/395a2edfd7741b5cdce7997bf8d4018d0e4b10d9/keras/engine/topology.py#L2630) from keras accepted `**kwargs` and passed them to `json.dumps`. Therefore this is the one line solution:

```
print(model.to_json(indent=4))
```

It generate results similar to the example of @anton-vbr.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pprint.pformat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) to retrieve a pretty string:

```
import pprint
json_str = model.to_json()
formatted_str = pprint.pformat(json.loads(json_str), indent=4)
```

If you don't want to save a copy of the formatted json, rather if you prefer to save it to a file, you can use [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) and specify `stream=...` with a file handler:

```
pprint.pprint(json.loads(json_str), indent=1, stream=open('model.json', 'w'))
```

Comment: No error. Just no pretty printing. And this is actually expected, because I can't beleive `pformat` can parse JSON string. In example https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html here it accepts parsed JSON, not string. The problem is to_json() returns string.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Okay. You can call `json.loads` to convert it to an object. Look at my edit.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library.
Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

```
import json
json_str = model.to_json()
print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_str),indent=4))
```

To save it to file:

```
import json
json_str = model.to_json()
with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(json.loads(json_str), f, indent=4)
```

Example dataframe from pandas:

```
datetime            temp    weather
2017-07-27 02:00:00 22.94   light rain
2017-07-27 05:00:00 21.74   clear sky
2017-07-27 08:00:00 21.10   light rain
2017-07-27 11:00:00 27.69   clear sky
```

Results in:

```
{
    "weather": {
        "1501131600000": "clear sky",
        "1501153200000": "clear sky",
        "1501142400000": "light rain",
        "1501120800000": "light rain"
    },
    "temp": {
        "1501131600000": 21.74,
        "1501153200000": 27.69,
        "1501142400000": 21.1,
        "1501120800000": 22.94
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not indent it. Just double escape everything.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for pointing it out. it should of course be loaded first.